# Manually changing a .bgen accompanying .sample file: How to export a .txt file with two "header lines" from R?

Tags: r, imputation, genetics

I've had to manually change the [accompanying bgen .sample file](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/2.0/formats#sample) that comes along with my imputed genotype data (stored in `.bgen`), as it had missing sex information (all `NA`s) which I then filled in with 1s and 2s for the males and females, respectively. `plink` won't let me run the original `.sample` file that came with my data as-is, since there're `NA`s in the sex column, and I get `Error: Invalid sex code on line 3 of .sample file.`.

However, I've run into problems.

I saved my "new" `.sample` file first as a `.txt` file in R using:

```
write.table(samples, file = "samples_bgen.txt", sep = " ", row.names = FALSE, quote=FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
```

And this `.txt` output has 26,623 rows. The column names are the first header (`ID_1`, `ID_2`, `missing`, `sex`) and the first row is what *should* be the second header line `(0, 0, 0, D)`.  I then manually changed it from `.txt` to `.sample` (as I'm not sure what else to do.)

When I run `plink`:

```
plink --bgen data.bgen --sample samples_bgen.sample --make-bed --out data_output
```

I get "`Error: --bgen and --sample files contain different numbers of samples.`"

I have 26,622 samples in my main file `data.bgen`. There's one extra in the sample file because of that first row that needs to be a second header line. If I manually delete that second row `(000D)`, then I get the error message `Error: Invalid second header line in .sample file.`

So: how do I make that second row into a second header line? Any help would be much appreciated. I've been digging around on the web without much luck so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I met some problems with `.sample` as well (it seemed that `plink2` cannot recognize IDs in `father`/`mother` columns in `.sample` file), so I decided to remove two columns in the .sample. I did something similar as you did, but in the final step, I converted the modified `.txt` into `.sample` using Mac command line `cp xxx.txt yyy.sample`. The modified `.sample` worked without any error/warnings. But I am not so sure if such way to modified the `.sample` is okay.